Galaxy S10 5G phone won't charge or charge up to only 77~78% due to low temperature in room temperature
The Samsung Galaxy S10 5G phone is my sub-device only used for gaming at home under Wi-Fi.
When I plug in the charging cable, it sometimes or frequently won't charge at all or charge up to 70 or 77% and says that the temperature is too low.
However, I only use it indoors at around 21~24 degrees Celcilus (70 ~ 75 Fahrenheit) and the device is actually a little warm due to the heated battery, so it doesn't make sense that the temperature is too low.
I think there's something wrong with the temperature sensor..
Is there no way to fix it? I think to disable the temperature sensor which prevents charging when the temperature is too low, but I don't know if the user can do that by myself.

If it's running Android 10 or later, you can get a lot more detail about the temperatures of the different parts of the device using ADB. Please do that and edit the results into your question.
